# Error Lambda Function handler

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda

this is my lambda function-

```
import boto3

def send_function(event, context):

    valu=event['VAL']
    mname=event['MNAM']
    d=boto3.client('cloudwatch')
    d.put_metric_data(Namespace='WebStatus',
        MetricData=[
            {
            'MetricName': mname,
            'Dimensions': [
                {
                'Name': 'Status',
                'Value': 'WebsiteStatusCode'
                },
            ],
            'Value': valu,
            },
        ]
    )
```

and i get error - 
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function'"

Comment: While uploading the function, what name did you give for lambda handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happens when you define wrong lambda handler name while you upload your lambda function. The name of the lambda handler has to be `<your python filename>.<your method name>`.

So if your python filename is `hello_python.py`, the lambda handler should be defined `hello_python.send_function`. For more info, [read this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-programming-model-handler-types.html).